# SQL Log Shipping Two Databases using the same shared folder

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, log-shipping

I will configure Log Shipping for more than 1 database on single a server. And I wan't to know If I can use a single Shared Folder or if I have to create a Folder For Each Database.

What I mean is:

- **Does SQL know what backups to copy If I use a Shared Folder?**
- **How about the copy destination, can it be the same for more than one database?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each database will have its own job and will only copy the dbname_*.trn, so they can share the same source and destination folder.  The jobs format the log backup file names in such a way that they can distinguish the LS backups from regular backups and will only copy the LS formatted ones for that database.

Comment: Thanks I was wondering if the job was smart enough to only copy the dbname_*.trn, and also restore it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't ever log shipped multiple databases (only one) from the primary, I would implement with each log shipping install have its own shared backup and copy folders.